# template const correctness cant pass const object pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I have the template with this definition and call it as such.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Print(const T fooIn)
    {
        std::cout << fooIn->GetString() << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyObject
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    MyObject(std::string str)
    {
        this->str = str;
    }
    std::string GetString()
    {
        return str;
    }
};

template class MyClass<MyObject*>;

int main()
{
    const MyObject* foo = new MyObject("test");
    MyClass<MyObject*>* bar = new MyClass<MyObject*>();
    
    bar->Print(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error: "Cannot initialize a parameter of type `Object *` with an lvalue of type `const Object *`". I'm using Clangd

Since `T=Object*` why would `const T` not equal `const Object *`?
I think that instead it has resolved to `Object* const`
And how would I make it so it has the desired functionality of being constant to the object it points to and I don't want to change the instantiation to `const Object *`

Comment: Const object* is a non const pointer to a const object

Comment: @AndyG It is, I mistyped the question, edited.

Comment: Pointers are weird like that. I suggest you write a specialization for pointers

Comment: Never written one of them, but I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestion @AndyG

Comment: @PepijnKramer Cheers for the really constructive feedback

Comment: I withdrew it... because it was indeed not helpful. But still it would be helpful for us if you have a minimal reproducible example that could mostly compile.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Fair enough, didn't want to code dump on here, thought the simpler the better

Comment: @MartyVestor Make sure you **post code that we can just copy-paste into a compiler and reproduce the problem/error**. It is called a [mcve] here.

Comment: `const T` with `T= Object *` is `Object* const` and not `const Object*`( which is`Object const*`)

Comment: `MyClass<MyObject const*>* bar = new MyClass<MyObject const*>();` (Also, the code doesn't work because `Print` is **private**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others (including myself in the comments) have mentioned, `const T` resolves to a `T* const`, or more concretely in your case `Object* const`.

This doesn't jive well when you have a function that looks like this:

```
void Print(const T fooIn)
```

There are two approaches here, which I'm going to list in order of my recommendation:

### Approach 1, don't instantiate the template with a pointer type

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void Print(const T& fooIn) const
    {
        std::cout << fooIn.GetString() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Which you'd call like so:

```
class MyObject
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    MyObject(std::string str)
    {
        this->str = str;
    }
    std::string GetString() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    const MyObject* foo = new MyObject("test");
    MyClass<MyObject> bar;
    bar.Print(*foo);
    delete foo;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aznqY5cze)

If you must, add an overload to `Print` that takes a pointer to const:

```
    void Print(const T& fooIn) const
    {
        std::cout << fooIn.GetString() << std::endl;
    }
    void Print(const T* const fooIn) const
    {
        Print(*fooIn);
    }
```

called like so:

```
int main()
{
    const MyObject* foo = new MyObject("test");
    MyClass<MyObject> bar;
    bar.Print(*foo); // non-pointer
    bar.Print(foo); // pointer
    delete foo;
}
```

---

### Approach 2, if you must, write a partial template specialization for your class:

```
template<class T>
struct MyClass;

template<class T>
struct MyClass<T*> // specialized for T*
{
    void Print(const T* const fooIn)
    {
        std::cout << fooIn->GetString() << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyObject
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    MyObject(std::string str)
    {
        this->str = str;
    }
    std::string GetString() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};
```

Called like so:

```
int main()
{
    const MyObject* foo = new MyObject("test");
    MyClass<MyObject*> bar;
    bar.Print(foo);
    delete foo;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3rah1Eh6n)

---

<sup>N.B. There's probably a tagged dispatch implementation here, but I don't want to even try</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the const in `const T` is **top-level**. This means that for `T= Object*`, we will get `const T` as `Object *const`.

Now, the type of `objPtr` is `const Object*` which has a **low-level const**. Essentially, you're trying to pass an argument which has low-level const to a parameter with a top-level const which is not allowed.

---

Basically, it fails for the same reason the following fails:

```
const Object* objPtr; 
Object *const ptr = objPtr; //fails for same reason: low-level const is not ignored
```